claim on exact triangles in derived categories
I am reading a paper and I came across a specific claim. I have an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ and a bounded derived category $\mathcal{D}^b(\mathcal{A})$. Consider non-zero  $X\in\mathcal{D}^b(\mathcal{A})$, such as
$$...\rightarrow  0\rightarrow 0\rightarrow X_n \rightarrow X_{n-1}\rightarrow ... X_2 \rightarrow X_1\rightarrow 0\rightarrow 0\rightarrow ...$$
The claim is that each bounded complex $X$ fits into an exact triangle $X'\rightarrow X\rightarrow X''\rightarrow X[1]$ obeying the rule $\mathcal{l}(X)=\mathcal{l}(X')+1$ and $\mathcal{l}(X'')=1$ with $\mathcal{l}(X):=\text{card}\{n\in\mathbb{Z}|X_n\neq 0\}$.
I know that from a short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0$$
in $\mathcal{A}$ we can construct an exact
triangle $$A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow A[1]$$ in $\mathcal{D}^b(\mathcal{A})$ if we consider the objects $A,B,C$ as concentrated at a particular degree.
For addressing the problem, as a trial approach, I constructed the following
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
... @>>> 0 @>>> 0 @>>> X_{n-1} @>>> X_{n-2} @>>> ... @>>> X_2 @>{}>> X_1 @>>> 0@>>> ...\\
@V{}VV  @V{0}VV  @V{\iota}VV  @V{\iota}VV @V{\iota}VV @V{\iota}VV @V{\iota}VV @V{\iota}VV   @V{0}VV\\
... @>>> 0 @>>> X_n @>{f_{n-1}}>> X_{n-1} @>{f_{n-2}}>> X_{n-2} @>>> ... @>{}>> X_{2} @>{f_{1}}>> X_1@>>> 0 @>>> ...\\
@V{}VV  @V{0}VV  @V{\pi}VV  @V{0}VV @V{0}VV @V{0}VV @V{0}VV @V{0}VV  @V{0}VV\\
... @>>> 0 @>>> X_n @>>> 0 @>>> 0 @>>> ... @>{}>> 0 @>>>0 @>>> 0 @>>> ...\\
@V{}VV  @V{0}VV  @V{0(?)}VV  @V{0}VV @V{0}VV @V{0}VV @V{0}VV @V{0}VV  @V{0}VV\\
... @>>> 0 @>>> X_{n-1} @>{f_{n-2}}>> X_{n-2} @>>> ... @>>> X_2 @>{f_{1}}>> X_1 @>>> 0 @>>>  0@>>> ...\\
\end{CD}
$$
The middle morphism is supposed to be a quotient. The lowermost morphism is a zero morphism. I am not sure whether the authors had this very simple construction in mind. The construction seems to be in line with another triangle $B\rightarrow C\rightarrow A[1]\rightarrow B[1]$.
The paper I am reading is Chen, Xiao-Wu, and Henning Krause. "Introduction to coherent sheaves on weighted projective lines." arXiv preprint arXiv:0911.4473 (2009). The claim is found in a proof in the middle of page 21.

What you do is correct and is usually called "stupid truncation".
